# Adding buttons horizontally inside a vertical stackview

Tags: swift

I'm new to swift and I'm following this tutorial: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ImplementingACustomControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH19-SW1
which involves adding five buttons in a row so users can add star ratings. I'm trying to programmatically add multiple buttons horizontally to the bottom of my vertical stackview. The buttons are showing up, but they're laid out vertically instead of horizontally. When I make the stackview axis horizontal, everything becomes horizontal, which isn't what I want either. Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class RatingControl: UIStackView {

    // MARK: init
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupButtons()
    }
    
    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setupButtons()
    }
    
    // MARK: Button Action
    @objc func ratingButtonTapped(button: UIButton) {
        print("Button pressed ")
    }
    
    // MARK: Properties
    private var ratingButtons = [UIButton]()
    var rating = 0
    
    // MARK: Private Methods
    private func setupButtons() {
        
        for _ in 0..<5 {
            // Create the button
            let button = UIButton()
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        
            // Add constraints
            button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44.0).isActive = true
            button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44.0).isActive = true
            
            // Setup the button action
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(RatingControl.ratingButtonTapped(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            
            // Add the button to the stack
            addArrangedSubview(button)
            
            // Add the new button to the rating button array
            ratingButtons.append(button)
        }
    }
    
}
```

and this is my viewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    
    // MARK: Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var mealNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var photoImageView: UIImageView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Handle the text field’s user input through delegate callbacks.
        nameTextField.delegate = self
        
    }
    
    // MARK: UITextFieldDelegate
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        // Hide the keyboard
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
    
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        mealNameLabel.text = nameTextField.text
    }
    
    // MARK: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        // The info dictionary may contain multiple representations of the image. You want to use the original.
        guard let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage else {
            fatalError("Expected a dictionary containing an image, but was provided the following: \(info)")
        }
    
        // Set photoImageView to display the selected image.
        photoImageView.image = selectedImage
        
        // Dismiss the picker.
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    // MARK: Actions
    @IBAction func selectImageFromPhotoLibrary(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        // Hide the keyboard.
        nameTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        
        // UIImagePickerController is a view controller that lets a user pick media from their photo library.
        let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        
        // Only allow photos to be picked, not taken.
        imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        
        // Make sure ViewController is notified when the user picks an image.
        imagePickerController.delegate = self
        present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    @IBAction func setDefaultLabelText(_ sender: UIButton) {
        mealNameLabel.text = "Default Text"
    }
    
}
```

This is what I'm getting:

[image]

and this is what I want to get:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What result do you want? Can you give a picture of that?

Comment: Just edited @matt!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a horizontal stack view inside your vertical stack view.

Then put the buttons into the horizontal stack view.

Stack views are intended to be nested. And they have almost no effect on performance no matter how many you add so don’t worry about nesting them.

Edit...

Your “buttons” is a stack view. So when you add them to your vertical stack view they will get added with the default axis of a stack view. (Vertical)

In the nib you need to change the axis of the buttons. Not the stack view they are in.

Or... in your code set `self.axis = .vertical`

Comment: That's what I was thinking...but the tutorial makes no mention of adding a second stack view, and the app works with the code displayed above. Is this because the older version worked but the newer version doesn't?

Comment: I have no idea about that specific tutorial but a stack view is only horizontal or vertical. Not both. So the only way to have the buttons underneath the image and then horizontally laid out is to have nested stack views.

Comment: Hmm...where do I set the axis? I'm using a storyboard (instead of an nib? I'm not sure what that is) and the buttons aren't clickable. And if I add `self.axis = .horizontal` to anywhere in the code above, it makes the entire thing horizontal, not just the buttons.

Comment: Storyboard/nib same thing. Set the axis in your custom control. Oh... ok... where are you adding the image? What you need is... <stackView:vertical></image></customButtonControl></stackView> I think you have added your image inside the custom button control.

Comment: I've added the image in the view controller, to allow it to access photos from my library...I edited the question so it has the code.

Comment: But adding a horizontal stackview seemed to work, so thank you for that.